# Python with accents, how to write?

Tags: python, encode, codec

I would like to write a content into a file on my system.

I download a page with Requests and would like to write my r.test into a file.

To do that I use:

```
with codecs.open("output.sv", 'w') as tmp:
     tmp.write(r.text)
```

But I have this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tired this

```
with codecs.open("output.sv", 'w', 'UTF-8') as tmp:
     tmp.write(r.text)
```

But, I have a lot of accents and strange char like œ and they are saved like this �

What should I do ? Thanks

Comment: Files don't have intrinsic meaning. They are read with the encoding that you specify

Comment: When I download the content, I have this in headers 'Content-Type': 'text/srt; charset=' Dont understand why, maybe something with Requests ?

Comment: `Charset=` specifies how you read the file in a browser. The content type header is added by the web server. It is not part of the file